# PyDev: Unresolved import

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev

I use PyDev in Eclipse and have a custom source path for my Python project: *src/main/python*/. The path is added to the PythonPath.

Now, i want to use the library pyMIR: https://github.com/jsawruk/pymir, which doesn't has any install script. So I downloaded it and and included it direclty into my project as a Pydev package, the complete path to the pyMIR is: *src/main/python/music/pymir*.

In the music package (*src/main/python/music*), now i want to use the library and import it via: `from pymir import AudioFile`. There appears no error, so class AudioFile is found.

Afterward, I want to read an audio file via: `AudioFile.open(path)` and there i get the error "Undefined variable from import: open". But when I run the script, it works, no error occurs.

Furthermore, when I look in the pyMIR package, there are also unresolved import errors. For example: `from pymir import Frame` in the class AudioFile produces the error: "Unresolved import: Frame", when I change it to `from music.pymir import Frame`, the error disappears, but then I get an error when it runs: "type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'Frame'".

1. What I have to change, another import or how to include a Pydev package?
2. When I make a new project with a standard path "src", then no "unresolved impor" errors appear. Where is the difference to *src/main/python*? Because I changed the path of source folders to *src/main/python*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to download and install the pymir package. There is one project structure that works for me:

```
project/music/
project/music/pymir/
project/music/pymir/AudioFile
project/music/pymir/...
project/music/audio_files/01.wav
project/music/test.py
```

The test.py:

```
import numpy
from pymir import AudioFile
filename = "audio_files/01.wav"
print "Opening File: " + filename
audiofile = AudioFile.open(filename)
frames = audiofile.frames(2048, numpy.hamming)
print len(frames)
```

If I moved 'test.py' out from 'music' package, I haven't found a way to make it work. The reason why the project structure is sensitive and tricky is, in my opinion, the pymir package is not well structured. E.g., the author set module name as "Frame.py" and inside the module a class is named "Frame". Then in "__init__.py", codes are like "from Frame import Frame". And in "AudioFile.py", codes are "from pymir import Frame". I really think the naming and structure of the current pymir is messy. Suggest you use this package carefully

Comment: Okay, now I have added the music package to the python path: */src/main/python/music*. Then the error disappears in the pymir classes. But in my class, where I use the pyMIR under */src/main/python/music/AudioFeatures.py* the error with unresolved import remains. Also with `sys.path.append('music')`.

Comment: I thought your structure is "/src/main/python/music/pymir/AudioFeatures.py", isn't it? I mean put whole 'pymir' under 'music'. Then append python path and try to use it as "from pymir import AudioFile". Does it work?

Comment: The pyMIR stuff is in */src/main/python/music/pymir/*. The code using pyMIR is one level above in *"/src/main/python/music*. I added the path */src/main/python/music* into PYTHONPATH and use `from pymir import AudioFile`, but then I get the error "Undefined variable from import: open". Can it be problem with the static open method?

Comment: Could you paste your commands and error messages? And what happens if you call "import pymir" ?

Comment: In my example file using pyMIR (src/main/python/music):             `from pymir import AudioFile`                                      `from pymir import SpectralFlux`                                   Then using `audiofile = AudioFile.open(path)` I get the error "Undefined variable from import: open", but at runtime it works.

Answer (score 0):

add **"__init__.py"** empty file in base folder location and it works

Answer (score 0):

1. unzip the folder `pymir` to `site-packages`, make sure the path like

   ```
   site-packages\pymir
   site-packages\pymir\AudioFile.py
   site-packages\pymir\Frame.py
   site-packages\pymir\...
   ```
2. comment the content of the file `__init__.py`

   ```
   #from AudioFile import AudioFile
   #from Frame import Frame
   #from Spectrum import Spectrum
   ```
3. test it

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from pymir.AudioFile import AudioFile

   filename = '../wavs/cxy_6s_mono_16KHz.wav'
   audiofile = AudioFile.open(filename)

   plt.plot(audiofile)
   plt.show()

   frames = audiofile.frames(2048, np.hamming)
   print(len(frames))
   ```