# How can I solve this error in python package?

Tags: python

```
from pymir import AudioFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymir/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from AudioFile import AudioFile
ImportError: No module named 'AudioFile'
```

Please answer.Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004954/python-speech-recognition-module-object-has-no-attribute-microphone

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/23238633/3959965

Comment: I have installed pymir.

Comment: How can I set the path for the library?

Comment: sorry,I want to know how to set the path for library.